# refactoring will_paginate attributes in a controller query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, helper

Hey. I am using the following line over and over in my controller index queries. Does it makes sense to create a new application method to re-use it? Any suggestions on how I could extract this and perhaps pass the `:per_page` attribute a variable parameter?

```
paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 12
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely do this in your application controller.  I think since it's a one-liner, you're saving very little in terms of keystrokes and text.  Still, if you wanted to do it, you could put something like this in application_controller.rb file

```
# optional-- this lets you use the method in views as well
helper_method :paginate_helper

...
# optional, but safer
protected

def paginate_helper(obj_to_paginate, page_limit)
  obj_to_paginate.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => page_limit
end
```

depending on the scope that you'll use this helper in, you may want to add an if statement regarding params[:page].  paginate will work with :page=> nil, however you could get an error for params[] if params doesn't exist (i.e. you'd be doing `nil[]`, trying to treat nil like an array).

Answer (score 1):

Like it says in the [will_paginate README](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)...

You can define it like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 50
end
```

... or like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.per_page
    50
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have the first one in my model. but it doesnt help me with the problem I posted.